# Curious memory consumption of pandas.unique()

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, pandas

While profiling the memory consumption of my algorithm, I was surprised that sometimes for smaller inputs more memory was needed.

It all boils down to the following usage of `pandas.unique()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys

N=int(sys.argv[1])

a=np.arange(N, dtype=np.int64)
b=pd.unique(a)
```

with `N=6*10^7` it needs `3.7GB` peak memory, but with `N=8*10^7` "only" `3GB`.

Scanning different input-size yields the following graph:

[image]

Out of curiosity and for self-education: How can the counterintuitive behavior (i.e. **more memory for smaller input size**) around `N=5*10^7`, `N=1.3*10^7` be explained?

---

Here are the scripts for producing the memory consumption graph on Linux:

*pandas_unique_test.py*:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys

N=int(sys.argv[1])    
a=np.arange(N, dtype=np.int64)
b=pd.unique(a)
```

*show_memory.py*:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
ns=[]
mems=[]
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    n,mem = map(int, line.strip().split(" "))
    ns.append(n)
    mems.append(mem)
plt.plot(ns, mems, label='peak-memory')
plt.xlabel('n')
plt.ylabel('peak memory in KB')
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
plt.ylim(0,ymax)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

*run_perf_test.sh*:

```
WRAPPER="/usr/bin/time -f%M" #peak memory in Kb
N=1000000
while [ $N -lt 100000000 ]
do
   printf "$N "
   $WRAPPER python pandas_unique_test.py $N
   N=`expr $N + 1000000`
done
```

And now:

```
sh run_perf_tests.sh  2>&1 | python show_memory.py
```

Comment: Each time there is a big step up in memory usage, the size of the step appears to double the same way memory allocation algorithms tend to work, and exponential backoffs in network collisions. Just an observation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AKX answers explains why memory consumption increases in jumps, but doesn't explain, why it may decrease with more elements - this answer fills the gap.

`pandas` uses `khash`-map for finding of unique elements.  When a hash-map is created, the number of elements in array [is used as a hint](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2dadd0f48949182dda412eb4032b5234c43c83c1/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L375):

```
def unique(values):
    ...
    table = htable(len(values))
    ...
```

However, the [meaning of the hint](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2dadd0f48949182dda412eb4032b5234c43c83c1/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi.in#L271) is "there will be n values in the map":

```
cdef class {{name}}HashTable(HashTable):

    def __cinit__(self, int64_t size_hint=1):
        self.table = kh_init_{{dtype}}()
        if size_hint is not None:
            size_hint = min(size_hint, _SIZE_HINT_LIMIT)
            kh_resize_{{dtype}}(self.table, size_hint)
```

yet the khash-map understands it as [we need at least `n` buckets](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2dadd0f48949182dda412eb4032b5234c43c83c1/pandas/_libs/src/klib/khash.h#L214) (and not we need a place for `n` elements):

```
SCOPE void kh_resize_##name(kh_##name##_t *h, khint_t new_n_buckets)
...
```

The are two important implementation details about the number of buckets in khash-map:

- the number of buckets is [power of 2](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2dadd0f48949182dda412eb4032b5234c43c83c1/pandas/_libs/src/klib/khash.h#L219),
- at most 77% of buckets can be occupied, otherwise the size will be doubled ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2dadd0f48949182dda412eb4032b5234c43c83c1/pandas/_libs/src/klib/khash.h#L158) + [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2dadd0f48949182dda412eb4032b5234c43c83c1/pandas/_libs/src/klib/khash.h#L221))

What are the consequences? Let's take a look at an array with 1023 elements:

- the hash-map will have 1024 buckets (the smallest power of two bigger than the number of elements) at the begining, but enough place only for ca. 800 elements (i.e. 77% from 1024).
- after adding ca. 800 elements, the size will be udjusted to 2048 elements (the next power of 2), that means the peak consumption will be **3072** (the old and the new arrays at the same time are needed).

What happens for an array with 1025 elements?

- the hash-map will have 2048 buckets (the smallest power of two bigger than the number of elements) at the begining and enough place only for ca. 1600 elements (i.e. 77% from 2048).
- the will be no rehashing, the peak consumption will stay at **2048** and thus need less memory.

This memory-consumption pattern will happen with every doubling of the array size.  This is what we observe.

Explanation for smaller effects:

- every second jump of memory consumption isn't accompanied with an decrease: the unique elements are stored in the vector which [quadruples its size](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2dadd0f48949182dda412eb4032b5234c43c83c1/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi.in#L94) (such visible every second doubling of the size). The elements must be copied, such twice the memory is commited/used and thus hides smaller usage of the hash-map.
- the consumption increases linearly inbetween: As elements are added to the unique's-vector more and more memory pages get commited: used `np.resize` zeroes additonal memory which doesn't commit it (at least on Linux).

---

Here is a small experiment showing, that `np.zeros(...)` doesn't commit memory but only reserves it:

```
import numpy as np
import psutil
process = psutil.Process()
old = process.memory_info().rss
a=np.zeros(10**8)
print("commited: ", process.memory_info().rss-old)
# commited:  0, i.e. nothign
a[0:100000] = 1.0
print("commited: ", process.memory_info().rss-old)
# commited:  2347008, more but not all

a[:] = 1.0
print("commited: ", process.memory_info().rss-old)
# commited:  799866880, i.e. all
```

NB: `a=np.full(10**8, 0.0)` would commit memory directly.

Answer (score 7):

Let's see...

[`pandas.unique`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2156431c3a673fbfb720983474d3cb4edc92c332/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L283-L378) says it's a "hash-table based unique".

It calls [this function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2156431c3a673fbfb720983474d3cb4edc92c332/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L187-L221) to acquire the correct hash table implementation for your data, namely [`htable.Int64HashTable`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2156431c3a673fbfb720983474d3cb4edc92c332/pandas/_libs/hashtable.pxd#L16-L20).

The hash table is initialized with `size_hint` = the length of your value vector. That means `kh_resize_DTYPE(table, size_hint)` gets called.

Those functions are defined (templated) [here in `khash.h`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2156431c3a673fbfb720983474d3cb4edc92c332/pandas/_libs/src/klib/khash.h#L225-L226).

It seems to allocate `(size_hint >> 5) * 4 + (size_hint) * 8 * 2` bytes of memory for the buckets (maybe more, maybe less, I might be off here).

Then, [`HashTable.unique()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi.in#L462-L502) is called.

It allocates an empty `Int64Vector`, which seem to [quadruple](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi.in#L92) their size whenever they get filled, starting from [128](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7f7f3d49bba842881b5f26a4fe973a6f3eca8757/pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyx#L53).

It then iterates over your values, figuring out whether they're in the hash table; if not, they get added to both the hash table and the vector. (This is where the vector may grow; the hash table shouldn't need to grow due to the size hint.)

Finally, a NumPy `ndarray` is made to point at the vector.

So uh, I think you're seeing the vector size quadrupling at certain thresholds (which should be, if my late-night math stands,

```
>>> [2 ** (2 * i - 1) for i in range(4, 20)]
[
    128,
    512,
    2048,
    8192,
    32768,
    131072,
    524288,
    2097152,
    8388608,
    33554432,
    134217728,
    536870912,
    2147483648,
    8589934592,
    34359738368,
    137438953472,
    ...,
]
```

Hope this sheds some light at things :)

Comment: Thanks for this analysis, yet somehow I don't see, where the curious behavior (i.e. less memory for smaller inputs) is explained, for example all values in your sequence are growing. Do I miss something crucial in your answer, which would explain it?

Comment: You're probably missing nothing. I'm aware the answer isn't a full answer in any way... Anyway, here's my code – I wanted to reproduce the results, and I see the same memory usage pattern. https://github.com/akx/so51485816